# jquery - how to get the value

Tags: jquery

My Table is Like This, I want to Get the value it is between `<a>` and `</a>`,Any one can help me please,Thank you.

```
   <table id="depart_me" class="tbl1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="rower bgyellow">
    <td width="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30">
    </td>

    <td colspan="4">
        Hai
    </td>

    <td bgcolor="#e2fdba" style="-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; text-align: center; width: 100px;">
    <div class="d_totprice" align="center" style="margin-left: 10px; float: left;">
    <a class="farebreakup" href="javascript:void(0);">5996</a>
    </div>
    </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: where do you want the value from? Also first code snippet is not valid. Please reread the question yourself, and re-write it so we can get it

Comment: dude you could've made extra efforts to make your question clearer .. no one will be able to guess what you wanna acheive .

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
var value_of_anchor = $('a.farebreakup','#depart_me').text();
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks to Šime Vidas for the inspiration and to ipr101 for pointing out the typo!

Comment: Your selector has a typo, the code in Šime Vidas's comment to my answer contains the exact same typo. If you were inspired by the comment you should credit it in your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#depart_me").find("a.farebreakup").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, try this -

```
$("table#depart_me a.farebreakup").text()
```

As per Šime Vidas's comment below, the following selector would be more efficient -

```
$('a.farebreakup','#depart_me').text()
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wdwB3/

Comment: Better: `$( 'a.ferebreakup', '#depart_me' )`

Comment: @Šime Vidas - why better? Would that be faster?

Comment: Yes, it would be faster - [see here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-adding-context-to-selector-queries). The second argument is the context. The context narrows down the selector query. What your query does is it searches for all `a.farebreakup` elements on the **entire page**, and then filters out those who don't have a `#depart_me` ancestor. This is not what you want. You want to **first** find the `#depart_me` element, and then search for `a.ferebreakup` elements **only** inside that element. Defining a context enables you to do that.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, thanks for the explanation, I've updated my answer accordingly.